# serial port resend recived data back to pc

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, avr, atmelstudio

I'm working with atxmega avr, I want to send a pattern of bytes to the MC and when it's complete and valid the MC Reply the pattern back to the PC, the pattern sent is an array of 8 bytes, I tried to find-out the problem but not succeeded :(, I don't know what's the problem with my code.
knowing that serial port is working fine.
my code is here:

```
    while (1)
{

     if (sampling_flag==1)
      {
          sampling_flag=0;
          tx_buf2[i] =  usart_getchar(&USARTF0);
          i++;

                 if (tx_buf2[0]== 0x01 && i==7)
                  {
                      for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                      {
                      usart_putchar(&USARTF0, tx_buf2[i]);
                      }   
                  }
             if(i==7)
             i=0;
            /*  
        if (!fifo_is_empty(&rx_fifo))
          {

                  fifo_pull_uint8(&rx_fifo, &byteToSend);
                  usart_putchar(&USARTF0, received_byte);
          }
          */
      } 
}//end of while(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to use "j" in usart_putchar like below

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
 {
    usart_putchar(&USARTF0, tx_buf2[j]);
 }
```

Your current code may reply only `tx_buf2[7]`.